# how to using navbar and div tag as fixed

Tags: html, css, nav

I wanted to build a website from scratch, I started adding nav bar which seems to work fine and after that I added a few div tags as "fixed".

I need it to be in such a way that when I scroll the nav bar should be fixed and the rest of the content to be scrolled...

I have attached the project below

Comment: you have not attached the project below...

Comment: I think you forgot to add the link to the project!  Either way, adding 'position:fixed' and 'top:0' to the nav bar should accomplish this.

Comment: I am sorry.. I am new to stack overflow as well as a beginner developer :( Please find the attachment in the below location  https://app.box.com/s/5iyj5jc5n3gzah5xwpyt

Comment: I tried doing as you mentioned and the nav bar disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have a solution for your problem.
In your project  **#navber**  element overlap the **section** element when you going to set **position:fixed** .Now if you set any positive value of z-index for section, then it overlaps navbar element
You just have to set one property...

```
section{
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
}
```

Fixed elements are those elements which removed from the flow of document.
Without any z-index value elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top).
but now section element overlaps navbar.set property for navbar as follow

```
#navbar{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: I want my nav bar to be in the same place even while the page is being scrolled....

Comment: For now I have put up a navigation bar and a few div tags...and how I want them to be is ....I want the navigation bar to be static when I scrolldown the page. Example ::http://metric.webflow.com/  all the other content of the page should scroll but navigation bar should remain the same

Comment: you just add one property to your navigation bar z-index:1;

Comment: sorry ... I did not understand

Comment: i just want you to add `section{position:fixed;z-index:1}` this in  your css file in you project....then you will know

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L8tc6/1/embedded/result/ This is the result I am seeing and this is not what I expect.... I want the Navigation bar to be on top of the page even when the page is scrolled down. like the previous example site which i ve sent you before.

Comment: look i know what you want and i just did that, it really worked....is it anywhere i upload your project to show what i see

Comment: I have uploaded my project here app.box.com/s/5iyj5jc5n3gzah5xwpyt      Please share the code if you see what I expect working

Comment: i just upload the project https://app.box.com/s/abzjv9ux4gydq5vi22tc go and check component.css. i  added some code to it....

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing I think I have a solution.

In your nav bar you need to put `<nav style="position: fixed; top: 0;">CONTENT</nav>`

This will make it never move and be stuck at the top `bottom: 0;` will make it stick on the bottom

**Update:**
Change your code to this:

```
<section class="color-1">
    <nav style="position: fixed; top: 0;">
        <a href="#cl-effect-14">Ailurophile</a>
        <a href="#cl-effect-14">Sumptuous</a>
        <a href="#cl-effect-14">Scintilla</a>
        <a href="#cl-effect-14">Propinquity</a>
        <a href="#cl-effect-14">Harbinger</a>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: I think I just tried that.below is my project https://app.box.com/s/5iyj5jc5n3gzah5xwpyt

Comment: your not implementing what I suggested in that code.

Comment: When I tried to make the nav bar fixed .. the div tag was moving above the nav bar

Comment: when I tried your recommendation the entire nav bar goes invisible

Comment: trying to add the same as you have recommended, inline statement effects the styles....  and when I tried to add into the style sheet it screws up and the nav bar goes invisible :P

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle of your project?

Comment: whats that ? and how do i do that ? I am new to web dev.  please dont mind teaching me :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/  put all your code in the boxes then save and click share. Then post the link to it here

Comment: Your code is to messy to make any sense of it. clean it up and I may be able to help

Comment: I assume it seems messy because i put all the style sheet together in jsfiddle ...I have attached the html and the css files in the below location.. please download it and unzip it.                 app.box.com/s/5iyj5jc5n3gzah5xwpyt